# Applicative operators <* and *>, type signature implication

Tags: haskell, implementation, applicative, type-signature

I recently saw a simple example that brought `<*` and `*>` to light.

```
validate :: String -> Maybe String
validate s =  if s=="" then Nothing else Just s

>validate "a" *> validate "b"
Just "b"
>validate "" *> validate "b"
Nothing
>validate "a" <* validate "b"
Just "a"
>validate "a" <* validate ""
Nothing
>validate "a" <* validate "b" <* validate "c"      
Just "a"
>validate "a" *> validate "b" <* validate "c"      
Just "b"
```

This shows that the effects are important even if the values they produce are not.

My question is about the type signatures.

```
(*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
(<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
```

- Do these type signatures actually imply the behavior shown above?

I can see how one could reason "Obviously we have an Applicative - so that says something about behavior in general. For operator `*>`, since we are throwing away the left value, the only *possible* meaning this function could have would be how the effect of the left hand side affects the entire operation."

In the case of `Maybe` - then it seems that yes - the behavior is implied. For `Either`, likewise the implication holds and the error would be propagated on an effect 'failure'.

Note I can only say the above because I *now* know how the implementation works, where my question pertains to the seasoned functional programmer who sees a signature like this the first time.

I have read where a type signature like `[a] -> b :: Int` (probably not real code there) all but implies the implementation as the length of the list.

I have also searched for "implying implementation from type signature" and found that people have-been/are working on such things - but in general cannot be done (Uh - without that new GitHub thing :--)

So perhaps I have answered my own question but would appreciate any other answers or comments. I am still new to Haskell and after a number of false starts over the years, it is finally starting to sink in. And I have only scratched the surface...

Thanks

Comment: As @WillemVanOnsem alludes to, `<*` and `*>` are supposed to be `liftA2 const` and `liftA2 (flip const)` respectively. The conditions specified in [the `Control.Applicative` docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) amount to that.

Comment: @duplode I think the allusion was more to the "wrong" implementations of `const` and `const id`.

Comment: @WillNess It was to both: Willem's comment mentioned the wrong implementations, and that we need laws to rule them out.

Comment: The [`Control.Applicative.Backwards.Backwards`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html#t:Backwards) wrapper gives you the opposite order (e.g. `Backwards fa *> Backwards fb` = `Backwards (fb <* fa)`), like [`Data.Monoid.Dual`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Dual) does for `(<>)` and [`Data.Ord.Down`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Down) for `compare`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> (*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
> (<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
> ```
>
> Do these type signatures actually imply the behavior shown above?

Of course not. The two operations could be implemented simply as

```
apR :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f b -> f b
apR a b = b

apL :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f b -> f a
apL a b = a
```

just ignoring the `Applicative` constraint on `f`.

And in the same way `[a] -> Int` does not imply the implementation being `length`. It could just as well be

```
foo :: [a] -> Int
foo _ = 42
```

But in both cases these are not the "right" implementations in the sense that the inferred types are different from the signatures given.

Your question is then, perhaps, a bit different, like, *suppose* there is an implementation with the *matching* inferred type. Does it follow that it does the thing we intended?

The answer seems to still be no. For one, we can define

```
apR2 :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f b -> f b
apR2 a b = pure (\a _ b -> b) <*> a <*> b <*> b
```

For some types, like your examples, it won't make a difference. But in general, doing the effects twice is different than doing them only once.

Another, even more meaningfully "wrong" implementation (with thanks to [Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791604/daniel-wagner) for the comments), is

```
apR2b :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f b -> f b
apR2b a b = pure (\b a -> b) <*> b <*> a
```

Now even your examples won't always work, because the *order* of effects is different -- it "does" `b`'s first, before the `a`'s.

Comment: There's not just how many times the effects are done, but also what order. For example, `foo fa fb = pure const <*> fb <*> fa` also has the same inferred type as `(*>)`, executes all the effects only once, and is still meaningfully different from it.